# Python source code: Which python projects are core and which are libraries?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2008

So at our work we are recompiling python 2.7.3. But I ran into some problems. Some of the projects don't compile. Ok, the docs said so.

But the listing of project files in VS 2008 is very confusing. Lots of projects start with an underscore '_'. Others don't. I take it that projects that start with underscore are non core projects? Perhaps they are library projects that depend on the main python DLL?

Another quick question. Some projects failed to build with an error message that $(HOST_PYTHON) is not defined. What is that?

Comment: What do you mean by "projects"? I don't think the Python source has such a concept; is it something your IDE defines?

Comment: In the python source, look in the PCBuild folder. There are 26 *.vcproj files in there.

Comment: Are you doing this by opening and building the `.sln`, running one of the batch files, or manually building the projects one by one? You _can_ do the last one, but you'll need to build things in the right order, and may need to do other steps. For example, you can't build Tkinter until you've built and configured python.exe, or have a different "bootstrap Python", because the build process is partly written in Python.

Comment: Also, out of curiosity… Why?

Answer (score 1):

The [readme.txt](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/PCbuild/readme.txt) inside the PCbuild directory explains what each project is for (although it may not be complete). This, together with some basic knowledge about what Python comes with, should give you enough information to figure out whatever distinction you want.

As for the underscores: All modules (except possibly for some special cases that don't have any actual C code in them) depend on the DLL. The "rule" is that projects that build modules are named for the module they build; user-visible modules don't start with an underscore, modules that are wrapped by a user-visible Python module do… But some of the oldest modules don't follow that rule exactly, and there are some exceptions in PCbuild itself—e.g., `sqlite3.vcproj` builds the `_sqlite3` module, not `sqlite3`. So, you can't rely on it except as a rule of thumb. And at any rate, it's not an important distinction for your purposes.

Anyway, what's "core" depends on what you mean by that, but you will definitely need at least:

- `pythoncore`: The main DLL that everything else uses.
- `python` or `pythonw`: The two top-level executables; you need one or the other (unless you're planning to embed Python instead of just running the interpreter).
   * `mkbuildinfo` and `mkversioninfo`: Tools that are used for baking the build information into other projects (I believe including `python`/`pythonw`).

If you have specific questions about a module, and you can't figure it out from `readme.txt` or the comments in the top of the main source file, you can ask. But briefly, the other projects should include:

- `pylauncher`: Builds the launcher that's used to make it easier to have two versions of Python and switch between then based on Unix-style shbang lines.
- A variety of modules implemented in C (plus `pyexpat`, which is used for building at least one other module, plus `unicodedata`, which may not have any C code in it but still has to be built).
- A variety of test tools.
- The `kill_python` helper tool.

---

> Some projects failed to build with an error message that $(HOST_PYTHON) is not defined. What is that?

Some projects, like the `ssl` and `Tkinter` modules, have a build process which is partially in Python. If you follow the standard build process, python.exe will be built and ready to use by the time you get there. But you can also "bootstrap" things by setting `HOST_PYTHON` to a pre-built Python.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the readme. I didn't see it among all other files. It did contain a lot of useful information. And I figured out what the HOST_PYTHON property was meant to point to.